# __doPostBack won't work if JavaScript is disabled

Tags: dopostback, javascript

If the JavaScript of browser is disabled then __dopostback won't work. I am looking for the alternative to this because I have radio button and drop down list controls in web page that should fire postback even if JS is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Autopostback cannot be made to work without javascript, as a workaround, you could put a button next to the radio button/drop down list only for those users with javascript disabled to manually trigger a post back:

```
<noscript><asp:Button ID="uxManualPostback" runat="server" Text="Go" /></noscript>
```

In the code behind (server side) you would then hook up the button's click event to do same thing the autopostback of the radio button/drop down list would have done.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but this would not work for me, alternatively I have to use something like a hidden button or button having look like radio or something else but I am not getting what